# Set up PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, database-design, plsql

i have got PL/SQL developer installed. However, it asks me to enter a password, username, and database. I dont know what to enter in this case. Am I going to need "oracle SQL client" to set up the database in advance? I am pretty new to databases that is why i am asking. Any help or suggetions will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

ali

Comment: Did you install an Oracle Database server? Or is an Oracle Database running in your premises?

Comment: Hi Wernfried, i haven't. I have got Pl/SQL Developer installed only. I guess the oracle sql developer"https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/" needs to be installed first. Through oracle sql developer i would be getting the name of the database, password and the user name which in turn has to be used for the PL/SQL developer. That is, at least, my theory. Unluckely, i dont know precisely what pre-steps needs to be taken in order to get PL/SQL developer used?

Comment: You need to have an Oracle database. Simplest would be the [Oracle Database XE](https://www.oracle.com/ch-de/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html) But it could be a longer journey to get it running.

Comment: excellent, now i know where to start from. Could you (if you dont mind) suggest better alternatives to "Oracle Database XE" i could read into? Thank you in advance

Comment: Actually a simpler option is to just register a trial account with Oracle Cloud. That lets you create autonomous databases in the Oracle cloud. Once the trial ends, you switch to an "always free" account that allows you to have two autonomous databases (up to 20GB each) and two "compute instances" (= cloud VMs). You can then access those cloud databases from your laptop using sqldeveloper (or PL/SQL developer if this is your preference)

Comment: Thanks for your advise godfrind, that sounds pretty good, I will check that option out. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one like to start learning SQL in general, then [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang.html) is even simpler than MySQL/MariaDB

It does not require any server, the "SQLite database" is a simple single file.  There are some "PL/SQL developer" -like tools available for free.

- [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/)
- [SQLiteSpy](https://www.yunqa.de/delphi/apps/sqlitespy/index)
- [SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)

Of course, SQLite has much less functions than big RDBMS like MySQL/MariaDB or Oracle, Postgres or SQL-Server. But it provides the basics and does not overload you as a student.

Comment: thank you wernfried, I will look into it, sounds suitable

Answer (score 4):

*SQL Developer* is to Oracle Databases what *Google Chrome* is to the Internet.
It is *not* a database that you can store stuff in but, rather, a "window" through which you can look at many databases, elsewhere.

You need to install and run an Oracle Database instance for SQL Developer to be of *any* use to you.

Honestly, if this is your very *first* DBMS, Oracle has a *very* steep learning curve.
You *might* be better off starting out with:

- **MySQL** - the *other* DBMS owned by Oracle *Corporation*), or
- **MariaDB** - the [still] free fork of MySQL (created when Oracle Corporation bought out Sun Microsystems and picked up MySQL as part of that "garage sale").

Of course, if you *need* to use Oracle Database - and all the complexity and rigour that goes with it - then you need to download and install it and then operate it.  As others have said, **Oracle XE** is the best *starting* point for Windows users.

Note: If you *do* go down this road and get XE up and running, then I *very* strongly recommend that one of the *first* things you read about is the **Backup** and [more importantly] **Recovery** of Oracle Databases.

Comment: An excellent explanation Phill, thank you for that and for your advise. I wil take your suggentions into account and think about it. cheers